# Create password hash from model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I need to hash a password from my "reset password" code. The obvious way to do it is deprecated:

```
class ResetPasswordsController {
    public function reset () {
        $this->ResetPassword->changePassword('correct horse battery staple');
    }
}

class ResetPassword {
    public function changePassword ($password) {
        $hash = AuthComponent::password($password);
    }
}

class AuthComponent extends Component {
    public static function password($password) {
        return Security::hash($password, null, true);
    }
}
```

... and it doesn't work anyway because I'm using a custom password hasher, of which `AuthComponent::password()` is obviously not aware.

Comments says:

> @deprecated 3.0.0 Since 2.4. Use Security::hash() directly or **a password hasher object**.

... but I can't figure out the syntax to call my hasher:

```
class CustomPasswordHasher extends AbstractPasswordHasher {
}
```

... esp. if I want to take app settings into account:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array(
        'Auth' => array(
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Custom' => array(
                    'passwordHasher' => array(
                        'className' => 'Foo',
                        'cost' => 10,
                    ),
                    'userModel' => 'MyUserModel',
                    'fields' => array(
                        'username' => 'my_username_column',
                        'password' => 'my_auth_token_column'
                    ),
                )
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

Is there an instance of the hasher hooked somewhere in either controller or model?
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a mechanism that seems to work:

```
class ResetPasswordsController {
    public function reset () {
        if (!$this->Auth->_authenticateObjects) {
            $this->Auth->constructAuthenticate();
        }
        $passwordHasher = $this->Auth->_authenticateObjects[0]->passwordHasher();
        $this->ResetPassword->changePassword('correct horse battery staple', $passwordHasher);
    }
}

class ResetPassword {
    public function changePassword ($password, AbstractPasswordHasher $passwordHasher) {
        $hash = $passwordHasher->hash($password);
    }
}
```

The tricky bit is that there doesn't seem to be an instance of the `AuthComponent`, probably because the *reset password* page is not password-protected. However, I can instantiate it myself with `AuthComponent::constructAuthenticate()`.

Answer (score 0):

In Cakephp 3.X you can do this in Model/Entity/User.php

```
protected function _setPassword($password)
{
    if(strlen($password) > 0)
    {
        return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
    }
}
```

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#hashing-passwords

Comment: This should work in CakePHP/2 too but it hardcodes both the hasher class and its configuration. It's okay as a quick hack but it isn't particularly robust.